# Swift Siesta redirect response to failure

Tags: swift, pipeline, siesta-swift

Is possible using Siesta pipeline, receive a success response, parsing it, and depending of the return, redirect it to a failure response?

My server response many times return a HTTP 200, but with a error message/flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by “redirect” you mean “transform an HTTP success into a Siesta error,” then yes, this is possible. The pipeline can arbitrarily transform successes into errors and vice versa.

Write a `ResponseTransformer` that unwraps the `.success` case, checks whether the error flags are set (whatever they are), and if so returns a newly constructed `.failure`.

For example, here is a sketch of a transformer that checks for an `X-My-API-Error` header on a 200, and if it is present returns an error:

```
struct APIErrorHandler: ResponseTransformer {
  func process(_ response: Response) -> Response {
    switch response {
      case .success(let entity):
        if let errorMessage = entity.header(forKey: "X-My-API-Error") {
          return logTransformation(
            .failure(Error(userMessage: errorMessage, cause: MyAPIError(), entity: entity)))
        }
        return response

      case .failure:
        return response  // no change
    }
  }
}
```

Configure it as follows:

```
service.configure {
  $0.pipeline[.cleanup].add(APIErrorHandler())
}
```

You might also find it helpful to study the transformer from the example project that [turn a 404 into a successful response with `false` for the content](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/blob/master/Examples/GithubBrowser/Source/API/GithubAPI.swift#L218-L221), and the one that [overrides Siesta’s default error message with a server-provided one](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/blob/master/Examples/GithubBrowser/Source/API/GithubAPI.swift#L200-L204).

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks Paul!